# .Select return wrong length

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to check if the field `data` of my `DataTable` records is set to '0' or '1'. 
All my local record is saved into `local_ds` DataTable. Now, the record that I want check is this: 
 `21a956af-f304-4c72-97cf-1ef08e8719fc`
for a better vision I paste here the content of my table (that is also the content of my DataTable `local_ds`):

[image]

How you can see the record that I want check have the field `data` set to 0. Now I perform the research through this code:

```
Dim local_data = local_ds.Tables(0).Select(String.Format("GUID = '{0}'", "21a956af-f304-4c72-97cf-1ef08e8719fc"), String.Format("data", 1))
```

The code above use `LINQ` to take the result, anyway, I pass the `GUID` field to search and the field data as `1`. This code should be return `local_data.length` equal to 0 but, instead, return 1 and this is wrong, 'cause I want to check only if the field `data` is 0 or 1. In this example the result should be `local_data.length = 0` 'cause in the `LINQ` query I specified clearly that I want find the record with `GUID = x` and `data = 1`. 

I already know that  this record exists in the database, the `local_data` variable must help me to recognize which type of valorization the `data` field have.

So, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in the code above, you are not using LINQ.

`DataTable.Select` is a method available starting from the 1.1 version of NET Framework and exists [in four possible overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(v=vs.110).aspx).

The one you are using is the one that takes, as first parameter, the WHERE condition and, as second parameter, the SORT order. So you are not really passing a condition `WHERE .... AND Data = 1` but the `Data=1` it is interpreted as a sort order of some kind.

The correct string for the WHERE parameter should be

```
Dim where as String = String.Format("GUID = '{0}' AND Data = {1}", _
          "21a956af-f304-4c72-97cf-1ef08e8719fc", 1)
Dim local_data = local_ds.Tables(0).Select(where)
```

Comment: Uhm okay @Steve, but "), 1)" should be: Dim where as String = String.Format("GUID = '{0}' AND Data = {1}", _
          "21a956af-f304-4c72-97cf-1ef08e8719fc", 1). An OT question: How I can set code style in comment like ctrl + k ? Anyway, let me try your solution.

Comment: In comment you could use the backtick character around the code you want to appear as `code`. Get the backtick with `ALT+096`

Comment: Good, the mistery go away. Anyway the code working now thanks for this, you're always the best, I wish you a good day :)

Comment: [Found this FAQ about markdown syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)